# Cannot get onclick function to run from within jQuery Ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
      var street = document.getElementById("street").value;

      $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          url: "{{ url }}&{{ qstring }}",
          data: { street: street },
          crossDomain: true,
          success: function(response) {
              function myFunction() 
              {
                alert("MyFunction");
              }

              $('#data_box').html('<h3>Pick a matching street</h3>');

              $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                  var string = String(value);                 
                  $('#data_box').append("<a href='#' onlick='myFunction();'>" + value.full_street_name + "</a>    Address Range: " + value.min_address + "-" + value.max_address + "</br>");

              });
          }
     });
  });
});

</script>
```

... and a div section where the data will be presented:

```
<div id='data_box'>
</div>
```

A button in a form triggers the ('#button').click function, which sends a request to a url, brings back json data, and presents it as hyperlinks in the "data_box div. After that, what I want to happen is when the hyperlink is clicked, I want it to trigger a function. I have an onclick in that link that calls "myFunction()" but it does nothing. I have tried using various jQuery functions as well but nothing seems to work. I also tried placing the myFunction function in various locations, including outside the jQuery but it also did not work.

Comment: is that a typo `->` `onlick='myFunction();` ?

Comment: it sure is! that was it ;)

Comment: Ahh, that feeling when the entire problem was caused by a missing `c`.

Comment: Why not using jQuery to handle your event handlers? `<a href="#" class="runMyFunction">`. Then use event delegation: `$('#data_box').on('click', '.runMyFunction', myFunction);`.

Comment: Which kind of event could be this: onlick ???

Answer (score 1):

And this is where you learn about scoping. You've defined `myFunction` inside the success handler, so it can only be called from inside the success handler. However, your `<a href="...">` lives in `window` scope (because in the success handler it's just a meaningless text string, and the `append` call turns it into a a real HTML element that has access only to the `window` scope), which doesn't know about your `myFunction` function, so now you're trying to call a function that does not exist.

In JavaScript, everything is scoped (i.e., "visible to things in") to the function they are in. Variables declared with `var ...` inside a function X don't exist outside that function X, and functions defined inside a function X don't exist outside that function X.

In this case, you want to do this, instead (noting that `value` is already a string, using `var string = String(value)` makes no sense):

```
var newElement = $("<a href='#'>" + ... + "</a>...: " + ... + "</br>");
newElement.click(myFunction);
$('#data_box').append(newElement);
```

Except you don't, because you're using an `<a href="#">`, and I'm 100% sure not trying to set up a link to the top of your page: *don't use `<a>` when you don't mean it*.

What you **really** want, is this:

```
var newElement = $("<div><span>" + ... + "</span>...: " + ...  + "</div>");
newElement.find("span").click(myFunction);
$('#data_box').append(newElement);
```

And yes, that doesn't have the `<br>` anymore either. Don't use break codes, use CSS.

Comment: dont agree with you on not using <a> tag , if you dont want href then dont add it instead of removing <a> tag

Comment: an `<a>` must have an href. If you just want click behaviour, you don't use the semantic link element. You use a span or a div or anything that doesn't have a semantic role assigned to it, and is styled as an inline-block (which a span is by default).

Comment: I do agree with that but semantically anchor is used for navigating from one place to other and if we slightly change this definition then it is fit for giving a feel of click so that an action can be made on it. Still no reason to remove it. Is this an rule that <a> must have an href, i dont think so ?

Comment: You can't "change the definition", it has a formal one. The anchor is what it's for: it's a hard link to another resource (either local, using #, or remote, using a qualified URL). If you need an element that does something that does not move the user's browsing context to either of these two things, it's not an anchor, and you should use something either better suited, semantically, or something that has no semantic role already. And it needs an href to act as link: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element (<a> is not a link placeholder here)

Comment: Is that so then Why facebook.com's login page have an anchor for "Why do I need to provide my birthday?" instead of a span. Is that right or that context is wrong ?

Comment: no idea, I don't use facebook. But any time you see an `<a href="#">`, that's wrong use of `<a>` under modern HTML rules. It'll seem to work (if the anchor is high enough on the page to make the jump-to-top not actuall scroll), but it's also just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() 
{
    alert("MyFunction");
}
```

is defined inside a function, for that reason it is not available to the inline event handler. The inline event handlers always use global scope, since they are executed on the DOM context, try to define the function globally

```
window.myFunction = function(){
       alert("myFunction");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with scope do not use inline events, attach them with jQuery. The function scope will work.

```
var outStr = "";
$.each(response, function (key, value) {
  outStr += "<a href='#' >" + value.full_street_name + "</a>    Address Range: " + value.min_address + "-" + value.max_address + "</br>";
});

$('#data_box').append(outStr).on("click", "a", myFunction);
```